# how do I use data from the database within my controller in laravel using eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to fetch the first name, second name and course from the database. My model is called Youth.

```
    $id = auth()->user()->id;

    $firstname = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['firstname']); 
    $secondname = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['secondname']);   
    $course = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['course']);
```

Then use the fetched data in my string called notification which is to be stored in my notification table.

```
     $notification = 'Internship application by ' . $firstname . $secondname . ' from ' . $start_date . ' to ' . $end_date . ' in ' . $course;    

    auth()->user()->notify(new Internship($notification));
```

When I do this the strings fetched from the database are empty. Here is my complete code and the result.

```
public function InternshipSearch(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required'
    ]);

    $start_date = $request->input('start_date');
    $end_date = $request->input('end_date');


     $id = auth()->user()->id;

    $firstname = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['firstname']); 
    $secondname = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['secondname']);   
    $course = Youth::where('id', $id)->get(['course']);

     $notification = 'Internship application by ' . $firstname . $secondname . ' from ' . $start_date . ' to ' . $end_date . ' in ' . $course;    

    auth()->user()->notify(new Internship($notification));

    //return back()->with('success','Internship application sent');
    return $notification;


}
```

I get the following result:

> Internship application by [] from 2019-01-08 to 2019-01-17 in []

The Youth Model

```
    class Youth extends Model
{
    protected $table ='youth';
    public $primaryKey='id';
    public function user(){
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code fragments in the question, not with links to screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Querying your Youth model with the same `id` multiple times is not needed. You are making three queries when one would be sufficient.

Here's what should work.

```
public function InternshipSearch(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user  = auth()->user();
    $youth = Youth::where('id', $user->id)->first();

    if(! $youth) { 
        return back()->with('error', 'Record not found');
    }

    $notification = sprintf(
        'Internship application by %s %s from %s to %s in %s',
        $youth->firstname,
        $youth->secondname,
        $request->input('start_date'),
        $request->input('end_date'),
        $youth->course
    );

    $user->notify(new Internship($notification));

    return back()->with('success','Internship application sent');
}
```

Comment: the above code gives me the error code 404 the page you are looking for could not be found

Comment: This is because of the `$youth = Youth::where('id', $user->id)->firstOrFail();`. `firstOrFail()` will return null if no `Youth` records are found for the particular user.

Comment: Is there a better way to handle the fetch. One that will not bring the error?

Comment: this bring another error: trying to get property of a non-object

Comment: Could you `dd($youth)` right after `$youth = Youth::where('id', $user->id)->first();`?

Comment: `dd($youth)` returns `null`

Comment: There's no `Youth` record for that particular user. The error message is obvious. Could you show us your Youth model and some sample data?

Comment: the `Youth` records are present in the database. Could it be that they are not being fetched?

Comment: Like I said, could you edit the question with the Youth model?

Comment: the youth model is included in the question